# Any way to include the same php file twice?

Tags: php, html, include

Any way to include to multiply PHP files that contain some of the same code without getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Feed() (previously declared in ...
```

I have one php file XML parsing to get info from a website. Then I have PHP file number two, with the same code as in number 1, + extra to strip down that output to make it easier to understand. So you can see modified text big and clear and get more detailed info smaller below.

Problem is that I get the an error when I include PHP files using the same code.

```
<h1 class="status">Status:<span class="open"><?php include 'open-closed.php'?></span></h1>
<p class="info"><?php include 'status.php' ?></p>
```

open-closed.php has the exact same code that in status.php but some extra aswell.
Status.php

```
  $url = ('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604');

      function Feed($url) {
        $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
        $result = array();
        foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
            array_push($result, $content);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $title = 'Ev 134'; 

    foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
        if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
            echo $f->description;
    }
```

open-closed.php

```
$url = ('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604');

function Feed($url) {
  $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
  $result = array();
  foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
      array_push($result, $content);
  }
  return $result;
}

$title = 'Ev 134'; 

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
  if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
$green_color    = 'green';
$red_color      = 'red';
$closed_text    = 'closed';               
$exception_text = 'could be closed';     

    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){


        if(strpos($f->description, $closed_text) !== false){


            echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                 '<span style="color:'.$red_color.'">STENGT</span>' :
                 '<span>ÅPEN</span>';

        }else{
            echo '<span>ÅPEN</span>';
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Both of those files declare the `Feed` function? And the declaration of them is the same?

Comment: I have updated question to show the content of both PHP files.

Comment: Why are you declaring the `$url` variable at the top, and then never using that, but rather passing the same string constant to the function? If the URL never changes, it maybe doesn't need to be a parameter to the function; if it does then pass the `$url` variable when you call the function or eliminate that unused variable.

Comment: If you are including the files that have same code... That means feed function is written twice... So you are getting the error... Function name is and always unique... You cannot redeclare that function... If you want to use both functions... Rename any function to some other name..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function to check whether a function is already defined, and skip re-defining it if so.

But that's not the best solution here, IMO. Rather, move `Feed` to a separate file, like `feed.php`, and use `require_once` to include that file in both other files. That way, when you update the function, it only needs to be updated in one place. You can call `require_once` as many times as you want, the "once" part of it means that PHP will only actually include the file the first time that this is encountered.